# How to make ul list items with pseudo elements stay inside the unordered list?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a unordered list with a list of items styled as tags. [See jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vymrwcnz/1/). But when the tags break into two lines, the arrow of the tags overflows the left side of the `ul`. How can I avoid this?

```css
.searchtags {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: arial;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:300px;
}

.searchtags li:not(.filterheader) {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 26px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 5px 15px 0 0;
  padding: 3px 6px 3px 15px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #4a4949;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
}

.searchtags li:not(.filterheader):before,
.searchtags li:not(.filterheader):after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

.searchtags li:not(.filterheader):before {
  /* the circle on the left */
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  left: 2px;
```

```html
<ul class="searchtags clearfix">
  <li class="filterheader">
    <strong>Tags:</strong></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add padding to `.searchtags`,
- changed `<ul>` to `<dl>`,
- changed `.filterheader` to a `<dt>`,
- and changed `<li>` to `<dd>`. With those changes in place `:not(.filterheader)` is no longer needed.
- All `<dd>` and `<dt>` are `display:inline-block`

#### SNIPPET

```css
.searchtags {
  /* Changed */
  padding: 0 0 5px 20px;
  margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: arial;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
}
dt.filterheader {
  /* float:left removed */
  /* Added */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
dd {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 26px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 5px 15px 0 0;
  padding: 3px 6px 3px 15px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #4a4949;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  /* Added */
  display: inline-block;
}
dd:before,
dd:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
dd:before {
  /* the circle on the left */
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  left: 2px;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: 2;
}
dd:after {
  /* the arrow on left side positioned using left property */
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #fff;
  border-color: transparent transparent #cacaca #cacaca;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  left: -9px;
  top: 3px;
}
dd a,
dd a:hover {
  color: #4a4949;
  font-weight: normal;
}
dd.right {
  /* the x mark at the right */
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0px 2px 0 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<dl class="searchtags clearfix">
  <dt class="filterheader">
    <strong>Tags:</strong></dt>
  <dd><a href="#">Tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span>
  </dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Long tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span>
  </dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span>
  </dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span>
  </dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Long tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: This one was pretty accurate and straight to the point. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, happy coding.:)

Answer (score 1):

Add enough margin so that the psuedo element is wrapped within the elements boundaries:

[image: margin-left]

```
.searchtags li:not(.filterheader) {
    margin-left: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by adding `padding-left` to the `.searchtags` and then a negative margin for the `.filterheader` so that only the 2nd row will be affected. Its like indenting a paragraph.

```css
.searchtags {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px 0 5px 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: arial;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:300px;
  padding-left:15px;
}

.searchtags li:not(.filterheader) {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 26px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 5px 15px 0 0;
  padding: 3px 6px 3px 15px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #4a4949;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
}

.searchtags li:not(.filterheader):before,
.searchtags li:not(.filterheader):after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

.searchtags li:not(.filterheader):before {
  /* the circle on the left */
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  left: 2px;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.searchtags li:not(.clearfilters):not(.filterheader):after {
  /* the arrow on left side positioned using left property */
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #fff;
  border-color: transparent transparent #cacaca #cacaca;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  left: -9px;
  top: 3px;
}

.searchtags li:not(.clearfilters):not(.filterheader) a,
.searchtags li:not(.clearfilters):not(.filterheader) a:hover {
  color: #4a4949;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.searchtags li:not(.clearfilters):not(.filterheader) .right {
  /* the x mark at the right */
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0px 2px 0 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchtags .filterheader {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding-left:-15px;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul class="searchtags clearfix">
  <li class="filterheader">
    <strong>Tags:</strong></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long tag</a><span aria-hidden="true" class="right" title="Delete">×</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `position:absolute`, so those arrows don't interact with anything outside of the `position:relative` positioned element. 
The first line doesn't have that problem because the first `<li>` has a non-zero margin-right. So just add margin-left.
If you want it to look exactly the same but the first of the line not overflowing then set the `<li>` to `margin-right: 0; margin-left: whatever`. Also set `.filterheader {margin-right:0}`.